# How to combine the output of two for in loops in Pyhton?

Tags: python, list, sorting, for-loop

This is a script for a discord bot, that gets all messages in a channel that have a reaction, checks if its the reaction you were looking for (`msgSplit[1]`) and checks if it has the amount of reactions you were looking for with `if num >= int(msgSplit[2]):`

```py
async for historical_message in message.channel.history(limit=historyLimit):
    for reaction in historical_message.reactions:
        if reaction.emoji == msgSplit[1]:
            num = reaction.count
            if num >= int(msgSplit[2]):
                print(reaction, num)
```

Since the channel history contained 5 messages with the specific emoji reaction we were looking for, we get 5 outputs.

```
reaction  2 
reaction  1 
reaction  1 
reaction  2 
reaction  3
```

How do I sort these outputs from top to bottom to have an output like this:

```
reaction  3 
reaction  2 
reaction  2 
reaction  1 
reaction  1
```

Comment: Collect them and sort them.

Comment: How would i go about collecting them, i know how to sort them.

Comment: Put them in a list

Comment: Putting them in a list with by defining an empty one first then appending num to it?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
async for historical_message in message.channel.history(limit=historyLimit):
    reactions = []                                # Create list
    for reaction in historical_message.reactions:
        if reaction.emoji == msgSplit[1]:
            num = reaction.count
            if num >= int(msgSplit[2]):
                reactions.append((reaction, num)) # Append to the list
    reactions.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1])        # Sort it
    for reaction in reactions:                    # And then print
        print(reaction)
```